# Get pod list for a node with specified condition (not state)?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there is a way to get pod list for the specified namespace, application, node name and pod condition? Applying lablelSelector to the query string it is possible to specify the application name, using `fieldSelector` I can select node name (`spec.nodeName==node`) and even phase (`status.phase==Running`). But status.phase will return all pods that are in specified phase including those that are actually in CrashLoopBackOff or located on nodes that were lost.

After analyzing the respond JSON I found, that there is a 'status' section that actually has 'status.phase' field mentioned above and section called "conditions" that stores an array/list of records of several "types" describing current condition of corresponding parameters. Among them there is a subsection (dictionary on Python terms) that has `"type" : "Ready"` and `"status" : <value>` that is what I need.

Full section of respond looks like this:

```
   "status": {
    "phase": "Running",
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Initialized",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2018-09-11T15:49:09Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "Ready",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2018-09-11T19:05:01Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "ContainersReady",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": null
      },
      {
        "type": "PodScheduled",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2018-09-11T15:49:09Z"
      }
    ]
```

It is obvious, that labelSelector and fieldSelector work using corresponding sections/fields of respond JSON. But I was not able to find the way to apply something like fieldSelector for "conditions" subsection. Like fieldSelector=conditions.type.Ready==True.

Sure, I can parse the respond in Python and select only pods heaving condition I need, but that does not look right to me.

Anybody have an idea how to specify pod condition in the API request?

Currently I'm using: `/api/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/pods?labelSeletor=app%3D<appname>&fieldSelector=status.phase%3D%3DRunning,spec.nodeName%3D%3D<nodename>`.

Comment: What version of kubernetes do  you use? It is important because they change api from version to version.

Comment: We are using v1.11.1.

Comment: this is not supported yet. You can create feature request on github https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues